# How to set currency format of input value in angular Reactive Form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to apply currency format in my amount field when user move to the another field then amount value will transform into currency format and when control focused then currency format will be removed.

I have tried with hostlistner to bind the event onblur and onfocus event  in custom directive, But I want without creating custom directive?

This is my HTML code.

```html
<input type="text" formControlName="amount" />
```

On the amount field I want to set currency format without creating custom directive.

Is it possible without creating custom directive?

Comment: Pls post your compoenent and html code to understand and help you better.

Comment: I have edited my question, please check.

Comment: This isn't enough, also add ur code u tried in component.

Comment: You can use pipes for currencies.  By using a boolean variable that holds the state of the field and currency will show/hide depends on that. You can read the documentation from here https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe . If i understood your question

Comment: If you want to avoid writing a directive (or installing npm libs for some masked input behaviors), then the only solution I could see is having 2 form controls in the form group, one for formatted, and one for raw input. Then some value syncing + some hide/seek play in the template. But when you think of it, it's actually directives that should be in control of behavior, because if you happen to need the same pattern in a different component this will be just a drop-in solution. Could be that the amount of time spent on writing a directive will be similar.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is come up with **Pipe** concept from it's **@angular/common** 
API.

> The name of the API which is specially implemented for Currency is
>   [CurrencyPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe#currencypipe). Please click on the link which is attached for detailed description.

Answer to you question,

You can use CurrencyPipe directly to you Angular component. Follow below steps to get it work.

1. Register **`CurrencyPipe`** to your respective angular(NgModule) **`Module`** under `Providers`. Please note that it should be imported from **`@angular/common`**

   ```
   @NgModule({
     declarations: [],
     imports: [],
     providers:[CurrencyPipe]
   })
   ```
2. Inject CurrencyPipe instance to your Angular(Ng) **`Component`** and use the method **`transform`** to convert the amount in target currency format.

   ```
   @Component({
     selector: 'selector-name',
     templateUrl: './design.html',
     styleUrls: ['./design.scss']
   })
   export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
       formGroup: FormGroup;
       constructor(private currencyPipe: currencyPipe, private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
       }
       ngOnInit() {
           const amount = 25.00;
           const amountInCurrencyFormated = this.currencyPipe.transform(amount);
           this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
               amount: amountInCurrencyFormated
           });
       }
   }
   ```

**Your expected outout:**
$25.00

Answer (score 0):

Might not necessarily be what you want but might be useful to someone else. You could try toggling between two inputs.

```
<input type="text" id="amount" formControlName="amount"(blur)="hideAmountInput()">

<input type="text" id="hidden-amount" (focus)="showAmountInput()"
 style="display: none;" [value]="form.controls['amount'].value | currency:'$' " >
```

```
 hideAmountInput() {
    (document.getElementById('hidden-amount') as HTMLInputElement).style.display = 'block';
    let input = document.getElementById('amount') as HTMLInputElement;
    input.style.display = 'none';
  }

  showAmountInput() {
    (document.getElementById('hidden-amount') as HTMLInputElement).style.display = 'none';
    let input = document.getElementById('amount') as HTMLInputElement;
    input.style.display = 'block';
    input.focus();
  }
```